# Finding the number of job switches

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

From the HR Schema, how can I get the number of job switches of each employee?

[image: ERD]

My try:

```
select e.first_name, count(*)-1 switches
from hr.job_history j 
  right outer join hr.employees e on (j.employee_id=e.employee_id)
group by e.first_name, j.employee_id;
```

It does give an answer but I'm not quite sure if it's right. Is the code written correctly?

[image]

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result? that really help

Comment: Verification can only be done if we have some sample data. Please share input and expected output.

Comment: That makes no sense if we don't know what you want to solve.

Comment: If that job_history table really only contains only a record for each time the employee changed job? Then I suppose that Sql should be 1 way to count the job transfers. But if that table also contains each change to the same job? Then it would be wrong. So you should also check what kind of "history" you're dealing with.

Comment: added the ERD. could you check now? @LukStorms

Comment: This might refer to the [Oracle sample HR schema](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/COMSC/overview.htm), however I get different results from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get incorrect results because you are grouping on `e.first_name, j.employee_id`. `j.employee_id` will be null for every employee that doesn't have a job history, and then your count will reflect the number of employees with that first name. (It doesn't show in your results, but in my Oracle HR sample schema I get 2 rows each for 'David', 'John' and 'Peter', who have no job history.)

Below I have changed it to use `e.employee_id` instead of `j.employee_id` in the `group by` clause:

```
select e.employee_id, e.first_name
     , count(*) -1 switches
from   hr.employees e
       left join hr.job_history j 
            on  j.employee_id = e.employee_id
group by e.first_name, e.employee_id
order by switches desc, e.first_name;
```

I have also removed some redundant brackets (there are no brackets in `join` syntax) and the `outer` keyword which is valid but optional (I have a thing about removing useless clutter). A `right outer join` is just a `left outer join` written backwards to confuse everyone, so I have reversed it for human readability.

Comment: `select e.first_name, replace(count(j.employee_id)-1,-1,0) switches
from hr.job_history j right outer join hr.employees e
on (j.employee_id=e.employee_id)
group by e.first_name, j.employee_id
order by switches desc;` Is this correct?

Comment: No. I posted the solution I think is correct and I gave an explanation. Why do you ask?

Comment: actually by the time you answered it, i did this. it gives the same result. that's why i was asking

Comment: Well it works, kind of, although it produces the results as text strings because `replace()` is a text function. It would be cleaner as `greatest(count(j.employee_id) - 1, 0)`. However this is still a hack to get around the issues I mentioned in my answer.